# Overlapping instances in Haskell when I'd expect it not to overlap due to constraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Reading the book `Real world Haskell` geting below example of Overlapping instances

```
instance (JSON a) => JSON [a] where
    toJValue = undefined
    fromJValue = undefined

instance (JSON a) => JSON [(String, a)] where
    toJValue = undefined
    fromJValue = undefined

ghci> toJValue [("foo","bar")]

<interactive>:1:0:
    Overlapping instances for JSON [([Char], [Char])]
      arising from a use of `toJValue' at <interactive>:1:0-23
Matching instances:
  instance (JSON a) => JSON [a]
    -- Defined at BrokenClass.hs:(44,0)-(46,25)
  instance (JSON a) => JSON [(String, a)]
    -- Defined at BrokenClass.hs:(50,0)-(52,25)
   In the expression: toJValue [("foo", "bar")]
   In the definition of `it': it = toJValue [("foo", "bar")]
```

By my understanding this won't be a overlapping, as [a] shouldn't be a choice, since The restriction on JSON [a] was that 'a' must be an instance itself of JSON. There is no instance of JSON for (String, a).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> By my understanding this won't be a overlapping, as `[a]` shouldn't be a choice, since The restriction on `JSON [a]` was that `a` must be an instance itself of `JSON`. There is no instance of `JSON` for `(String, a)`.

That's a misunderstanding. GHC does the instance selection taking only the instance head into account, and not any constraints on the instances.

```
instance (JSON a) => JSON [a] where
```

means for the purpose of instance selection the same as

```
instance JSON [a] where
```

also the context of

```
instance (JSON a) => JSON [(String, a)] where
```

is ignored for instance selection.

Thus GHC sees the two instances

```
instance JSON [a]
instance JSON [(String, a)]
```

and they both match the required

```
instance JSON [(String, String)]
```

that means you have overlap (regardless of what instances actually exist and what constraints each of the two instances has).

If an instance is selected, then the constraints are taken into account, and if they are not met, that is a type error.

Comment: By the way: slightly later on the book points out that you can use the `OverlappingInstances` pragma to "solve" the "problem" described in this answer. Personally, I don't understand why it's the way it is.. hopefully I'll grok it one day.

Answer (score 6):

These exist

```
ghci> :i ToJSON
...
instance ToJSON [Char]
...
instance (ToJSON a, ToJSON b) => ToJSON (a, b)
```

So there'd be an overlap even if GHC took context into account (see Daniel Fischer's answer).